# Clicking on overlapping divs

Tags: javascript, css

Let's just say that I have `main`, and I also have a `div`.

The `div` is smaller than `main`, and `div` is fixed on top of `main`.

Whenever I hover over `div` it is `display: none;`, and whenever I hover `main`: `div{display: none;}`. And if I click over `div`, I will be clicking over `main`.

So if `main.onclick` executes `myFunction()`, and I click on `div`, it will still execute `myFunction()`.

How exactly would I be able to do that? It probably uses js right?

Example code:

```css
body {
 margin: 0;
}

main {
 z-index: 1;
 background-color: #000000;
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
}

#div {
 z-index: 2;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 height: 20px;
 width: 20px;
 background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
}

#div:hover {
 display: none;
}
```

```html
<main>
</main>
<div id="div">
</div>
```

Comment: In HTML5 you can use custom tag. but it should be meaningful. And here  `main` a custom tag seems meaningless.

Comment: And a question is ...?

Comment: @KheemaPandey `main` is not a custom tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_main.asp

Comment: @julianavar use stopProgpagation() and preventDefault()
here is a link https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you need to register click event in javascript/jquery

```
<main >
</main>
<div id='div'>
</div>
```

JS:

```
 $('main').click(function() {
        $('#div').click();
 });

 $('#div').click(myFunction);

 function myFunction() {
        //Do your thing here or you can put anonymous function into click event.
 }
```

To make your div invisible on hover in js:

```
 $('main').hover(function(){
    $('#div').hide()
 })
```

Comment: and how would I make it so when I hover over `main`, `div{display: none;}`